# Angular & ag-grid: Facing some of the issues in SSRM (Server-Side Row Model)

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We are using Server-Side Row Model of ag-grid library version 26.0.0 in Angular 11. Currently we are using trial version of SSRM.

Some of the brief about the how we are doing SSRM with our code.

> We are using serverSideStoreType as "partial" and whenever we are
> moving to next page then we are calling the API for get the next new
> data from API.

Below issues we are facing with ag-grid library.

1. Example page size is 10 and we are clicking to next page then 10 row is showing "Loading..." with default icon of ag-grid and we have also tried with overlays and custom loader of ag-grid documentation but not getting any success.
2. With server-side pagination, when data is loading, the total number of items (rows) show as "more". (Example "X to Y of "more"")
3. With server-side pagination, when data is loading, the number of items (rows) on this page shows as "?". (Example "X to ? of Z")
4. With server-side pagination, when data is loading, the number of pages shows as "More". (Example "Page 1 of "More"")
5. We need to use this in an App that is intended to support multiple languages (right to left and left to right). As such we need to be able to translate the constant terms in the Ag Grid table as well, for example "to", "of", "Page", etc.. We typically use JSON files (one for each language) for translation of App terms, and would like to do the same for the said terms in Ag Grid. Is there a best practice to implement this for Ag Grid, so it can dynamically take these terms in the table from the JSON file?

Added some sample code.

```
var tableData = {
      getRows: (params) => {
        //  TODO: Call a service that fetches list of users
        this.queryString = this.getQueryString(String(params.request.endRow / this.gridOptions.paginationPageSize),
          String(this.gridOptions.paginationPageSize));
        api_call.subscribe((data) => {

            if (data && data.statusCode) {
              this.dataSource = [];

              for (const item of data.result.items) {
                const tableData1 = {
                  id: item.id,
                  name: item.name,
                  description: item.description,
                  creationDateTime: item.creationDateTime
                }
                this.dataSource.push(tableData1)
              }
              params.success({
                rowData: this.dataSource,
                rowCount: data.result['totalCount'],
              });
            }
          });
      }
    }
    this.gridApi.setServerSideDatasource(tableData);
```

Comment: Please add some code that you have written for grid. Have you defined custom datasource?

Comment: I have added the code in question. can you check ?

Comment: What is the structure of your api response? Are you getting totalCount in result?

Comment: Yes, I am getting totalCount from API response